# Was it just coincidence that "Barad-dûr?" sounds like an English phrase?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkien-languages

The first time I heard someone talk about Barad-dûr, I thought they were talking about a "barred door."  The meaning would be more than appropriate.  Is there any chance Tolkien happened to realize he could do this, using his own Middle Earth languages, as a bit of an inside joke?

Or is it just completely coincidence Barad-dûr seems like it could be so easily pronounced as "barred door?"

Comment: It was originally meant to be "Hodor"

Comment: Seems a bit of a stretch to me. It's not a door and it's not barred

Comment: don't prescribe to Tolkien that which was quite likely simply someone butchering the invented language ;)

Comment: Uh, except Barad-dur does NOT sound like "barred door", or any other English words.

Comment: @Martha - It sounds *a bit like it* in broad Irish accent.

Comment: With real languages, search the language hard enough and you'll find words that coincidentally sound like a word in another language. Example: boya means boy in Japanese, but the Japanese word does not originate from English.

Comment: Barad-Dûr translates from Sindarin as "Dark Tower".  Barad means "tower" and dûr means "dark".  No door. No bar.

Comment: The vocabulary of Sindarin didn't appear out of nowhere. Every word was *intentionally constructed* by a speaker of English. This is not a question of how real languages work; it's a question of how inclined Tolkien was toward making strained puns.

Comment: I don't really understand the downvotes. Didn't Tolkien explicitly use his expertise in linguistics to model Middle Earth languages from Old European languages? Similarities may ensue.

Comment: @Taladris yes, but in more subtle ways than that: linguistic features, and general sound palate, less so ripping off words wholesale (though he did of course use OE for his 'translation' of Rohirric.)

Comment: The phonetics of the Sindarin are completely different than English. It doesn't sound like barred door at all. "ba" sounds like the one in the word "ballet", "-rad" uses a hard "r" sound like in Scottish or German and the "u" in "dûr" sounds like "oo" in "book", but it's a long vowel and the final "r" is pronounced as the previous one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no evidence to indicate a deliberate connection.

Similar coincidences certainly *do* exist in Tolkien's work, with the most well-known being the name **Atalantë**, used for post-Downfall Númenor and suggestive enough of "Atlantis" that Tolkien himself remarked on it in a footnote to Letter #257:

> It is a curious chance that the stem √*talat* used in Q[uenya] for 'slipping, sliding, falling down', of which *atalantie* is a normal (in Q) noun-formation, should so much resemble Atlantis.

In this particular case it seems that the Quenya stem was pre-existing, and once Tolkien noticed that it could be formed to resemble "Atlantis", he deliberately chose to do so.

In the case of **Barad Dûr**, a resemblance to "barred door" doesn't even make sense; there is nothing in the books to make a connection between the Dark Tower and a barred door, and if such a connection were to be made, one would imagine it to be more appropriate to the Paths of the Dead ("the way is shut", etc).

You're going to have to attribute this one to [pareidolia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareidolia).

Comment: Another example is Baranduin which sounds like Brandywine. But "duin" means river so it was at least half coincidence

Comment: *Was* the stem TALAT preexisting? *The Lost Road* was written well before LotR (and the need for a bridge between the early versions of the Silmarillion and LotR), and it seems quite possible that Tolkien is being facetious here, adding a stem to the Quenya lexicon that could serve as a root for Atalantë after the fact.

Comment: Brandywine isn't a coincidence. It's a corruption of the Elvish name into the Common Speech.

Comment: I'd say there is a resemblance to a barred door.  What is a fortress?  Walls to keep people out.  That includes gates or doors that would have to be barred, so a fortress is, in many ways, a barred door to keep people out.

Answer (score 13):

["Barad"](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Barad) is used in other names:

- [Barad Eithel](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Barad_Eithel)
- [Emyn Beraid](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Emyn_Beraid)

As is ["Dûr"](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/D%C3%BBr):

- [Emyn Duir](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Emyn_Duir)
- [Dol Guldur](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Dol_Guldur) (Guldur = dark sorcery)

While it's possible that Tolkien designed all these words around "Barad Dûr" being a strained pun, it seems more likely to me that it's a coincidence.

Comment: That would be my thought, but sometimes when you find something odd like this, it turns out there might be a story behind it.

Comment: Barrad, Barad, and Beraid are three different words, pronounced in three different ways. (If it's not English, you can't just ignore the vowels and call it close enough.)

Comment: @Martha In this case, they do indeed all derive from the Sindarin word meaning "tower", per the links in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

"Barad-dûr" is Sindarin, and generally Sindarin has compatible sounds to Welsh and English lanuages, so it's possible that a Sindarin word might resemble an English word, but mostly as a coincidence.